# run Handlers one after another

Tags: android

I have this code, it works well if I use lights(); once
but if I use it multiple times like lights();lights();lights();... not so much. when the app run they seems to run all at the same time

```
public void lights() {
   try {if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)){
      cam = Camera.open();
      Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
      p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
      cam.setParameters(p);
      cam.startPreview();}
      } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
      }
    }
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {public void run() {stop();}
        }, 1000);   
}
public void stop(){
    try {if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH))
    {cam.stopPreview();cam.release();cam = null;}} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

How can I make the handlers to wait one after another? To wait for the first one to finish. I want to make an alarm but if I use ThreadSleep(); too much my app crash, probably thinks the UI is unresponsive

Comment: Handlers does run serially.

Comment: The braces are not balanced. Are you sure the code compiles?

Comment: probably I miss one or put one too many when I made this post, the code complies